# Linking to file without extension (.php removed through .htaccess) not working on one page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I succeeded in making .htaccess rewrite URLs so I can link to pages without having to define the extension. But, only one of the pages won't work.

The page is called 'games.php' and I link to it through `<a href="games">Go to Games!</a>`

But whenever I go to it, it goes to '/games/', as if it were a folder, and then gives an Error 404.

I don't know how to fix it. I checked, there's no folder or any other file called like this, and it works on all the other pages... (also on games?id=blabla...)

Here's my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Thanks in advance,
Dalionzo :D

Comment: Your `.htaccess` should work for every page. Are you sure its `games` and not `game`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it's games. And that's why I'm so puzzled, it even works on games?andsomeparametershere, but not on the 'regular page'.

Comment: Are there any other apache directives that might be taking precedence?

Comment: DO you have a .htacces prior to your current working directory? And post your folder structure also?

Comment: @liquorvicar I've looked around, but for as far as I know I don't think so.

Comment: @Starx no, all I have is my '/' and a lot of files including .htaccess and games.php in it, and a folder called gamesFold

Comment: What's showing in your logs? Especially your apache error log. Have you tried setting up rewrite logging to see what's going on there? (I think you need to do that in vhost context, don't think you can do it in .htaccess.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^games(.*)?$ games.php$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^games(/)?$ games.php [L,QSA]
```

**UPDATED**

Now it works without parameters too.

website.com/game.php?id=blablabla --> website.com/game?id=blablabla

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but thank you for your answer, but it's not what I needed. The problem is that it doesn't work WITHOUT parameters....

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I used your code and at first it did still not work, but an hour later or so it magically started to work. And therefore, I totally forgot to thank you. Thank you :)